# Getting the error "Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing" in postman

Tags: amadeus

Here's the information entered on postman
URL - https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token
Parameters:
grant_type - client_credentials
client_secret - {{My_API_Secret_key}}
client_id - {{My_API_key}}

Headers
Content Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

It returns this response : 
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing",
    "code": 38187,
    "title": "Invalid parameters"
}

Answer (score 0):

It's a `post` request. so you should pass these `parameters` under different type.

For example in python's `requests` library it would be inside your `data`:

```
requests.post("{}/v1/security/oauth2/token".format(url), data=YOURPARAMETERS, headers=YOURHEADERS )
```